# Not being able to maintain Wudu during Ramadan for Taraweeh prayer

Tags: sharia, salat, ramadan, wudu, taraweeh

When I don't eat, my body builds up a lot of gas. During Ramadan, I have this problem where I'm not able to maintain my Wudu for Taraweeh later at night. Trying to maintain it is actually bad for my body because I get really sharp stomach pains later and have a hard time eating during Sehri.

What suggestions do I have to pray Taraweeh with everyone during Ramadan with this problem?

Comment: Can you make wudhu again or do you pray in an area where it'll be tough?  You can wear khuffs or socks and it'll make it easier to make wudhu, just wipe over your feet.

Answer (score 1):

Well this hadith authenticity I'm not sure of, but still..

> Our Prophet said, “A person must make wudu (ablution) if he hears a sound or perceives a smell of passing wind (gas).” (Muslim, Hayd 26; Nasai, Taharah: 115).

These problems like bloating, flatulence, constipation etc, are very common and even might have prevailed before in the past. Especially in Saudi Arabia with limited water, it wouldn't have been said that whenever one passes wind, wudu breaks.

Try eating healthy foods and avoid Onions and Garlic([as stated in Hadith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13130/eating-garlic-before-visiting-the-masjid-ambiguous-hadith)) and have a plenty of water when not fasting. Check out for foods which do not cause a lot of gas. One good advice is have plenty foods with fiber. Also try googling natural ways to stop bloating and such.

Exercise regularly (lightly) in the month of Ramadhan, which many fail to do.

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: He may have a medical issue or a different body chemical composition. The way he wrote his post, it seems like its causing undue hardship on him just trying to maintain wudu.

Answer (score 1):

Allah says in the Quran:

> Allah tasketh not a soul beyond its scope 2:286

He Also says:

> Allah would not place a burden on you, but He would purify you and would perfect His grace upon you, that ye may give thanks 4:6

The prophet PBUH said:

> Religion is very easy and whoever overburdens himself in his religion will not be able to continue in that way.

Sheikh Sayyed Sabiq wrote in this book Sunnah Creed:

> People with unusual circumstances (i.e. women with "prolonged flows of blood"), people who cannot control their urine, people with flatulence, and so on, should perform one ablution for each prayer whether their problem exists all or part of the time or not. Their prayers will be acceptable even while their problems are occurring.

It was reported by Aisha (the wife of the Prophet):

> A’ishah said: "Fatimah bint Abi Hubaysh came to the Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, and said: ‘O Messenger of Allah, I am a woman who experiences Istihadah and I do not become clean from bleeding. Should I forget about Salah?’ He said: ‘No, that is from a vein; it is not menses. When your period starts, then stop praying, and when it ends, wash the blood from your body and pray again.’"

Many scholars say the same applies to a person who suffers from medical condition (constant gas passing for example). You can make the same Sunnah Prayers (like Taraweeh) with the latest Wudu you did for the last Fard. So you make Wudu for Isha, and regardless of what happens you only need to make Wudu before Fajir again (Hanafi + Hanbali). Shafi scholar performing only one Fard prayer is the way to go.

The best solution would be to find a medical solution if possible.

Source: http://www.islamawareness.net/Wudu/fatwa_concession.html