# Missed Prayer due to sometimes inability to keep wudu

Tags: salat

For the longest time I struggled with Praying. I had difficulty with keeping wudu. Sometimes I could keep it sometimes I could not. I found it extremely stressful so i stopped praying for 2-4 years. Then later I read that if you struggle with keeping wudu you can just do it once and then pray. Since then I have prayed everyday. My question is do I have to make up the prayers i missed?

Comment: This video may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2b4k09FEYc

Answer (score 1):

If you're not a woman, then the simple answer is **Yes**, I guess no matter which school of thought you want answers from.

I don't think there will be a difference in opinions in between schools, cuz this matter is a matter of Fard (compulsory deeds to be performed no matter what).

If you're a woman, then you don't have to repeat the prayers (Salah) which you missed during menses. (But you need to repeat the fasts though which you missed during menses in case it is Ramdan).

Helpful: "[Not being able to maintain Wudu during Ramadan for Taraweeh prayer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/not-being-able-to-maintain-wudu-during-ramadan-for-taraweeh-prayer)"

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: I guess, I need to ponder over this matter a little bit more. As, I'm not sure, if the person has to **make up the Salah which he missed when he was ill**. This case is analogous to that. If the person has to make up those Salah, then Yes, in this case too. Other wise, asking forgiveness would suffice I guess.

Comment: Also, because he was not praying, some people may suggest that he was in a state of Kufr due to a Hadith. Therefore him praying again would take him out of Kufr and he would become a Muslim again and hence wiping his previous sins away.

Comment: when a kafir becomes a muslim, does he have to make up the prayers? @Dinar

Comment: Well, if it is a sin to miss prayer, and converting to Islam will wipe all previous sins, I wouldn't think a convert/revert would have to make up the prayers, due to the fact that they were not sins.

Comment: http://quran.com/8/38

Comment: now, next question is.... does a person have to make up the prayers when he was (damn) ill??? @Dinar

Comment: Depends on the type of illness I would assume.

Comment: hmmm maybe if the person was too ill, then there maybe some excuse, ryt? but not on all easy illnesses ryt? @Dinar

Comment: It really depends on the illness, for example, if he cannot pray while standing up, he can praying while sitting down. If he cannot pray while sitting down, he can pray while lying on his back. If he is completely paralyzed, he can pray with his eyeballs and so on so forth

Comment: Here is a source regarding praying when sick: http://muslimcanada.org/fiqhch25.htm