# If you have continuous gas during prayer, can you purposely let it out?

Tags: salat

I have this very embarrassing problem with gas and anxiety, and it is continuous and affecting my prayer. I am physically so exhausted and tired because every time I pray I have to hold it in. I know that if you have continuous gas, then you can pray like that, but under that ruling can one purposely let gas out during prayer sometimes just to make himself feel better, even if he's physically capable of holding it in?

Comment: See also: "[Not being able to maintain Wudu during Ramadan for Taraweeh prayer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/13362/9123)"

Comment: One thing you can do that may help with reducing your gas issue is to do regular walking, running and leg-stomach exercises, that is if you are able to and based on your health and body condition. Also, not eating right before doing the payer may also help.

Comment: i have school and am in hurry, this will answer your question as i have no time: https://islamqa.info/en/22843

Answer (score -1):

Brother unless you have have a problem with gas do wudu again if you do have a problem ignore it because allah makes it easy but if you unsure ignore it and just believe you didn't as this is whispers from shaytaan it's supposed make you non focus on salah ok

Answer (score -7):

Yes you can, as it's a natural thing of the body, but make sure there is no one behind your back or you may make him feel uncomfortable.