# Eating onions can harm Angels?

Tags: source-identification, islamic-basis, malaikah

One of my friend said a person must not enter mosque after eating onions. Because it can harm Angels.

Is this true or can this be a cultural  belief ?

There are many hadiths about eating Garlic and not entering the masjid. I know bad odor can make other worshipers uncomfortable.

But my question is: can onions harm angels, and how?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [islam.se]. It probably has to do with the heavy mouth odor one gets after having onion and garlic. And I think there is also hadith in this reference.

Comment: meta discussion: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/why-was-this-question-reopened-and-then-edited-without-asking-the-op

Comment: I retracted my vote because now the question is clear...

Answer (score 1):

From the answer [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/13203/885)

> Jabir b. 'Abdullah reported the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) mying: He who eats of this (offensive) plant, i. e garlic, and **sometimes he said: He who eats onion** and garlic and leek, should not approach our mosque for the angels are harmed by the same things as the children of Adam.

As you can see from the hadith that Onion harm angels too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! According to the hadith quoted [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13130/eating-garlic-before-visiting-the-masjid-ambiguous-hadith/13203#13203), onions harm angels.

But as for how and why, I personally believe there's a metaphorical aspect in "harming the angels". But since there's always an underlying truth to any metaphor, I believe, it points to the fact that angels distance themselves from a person who stinks. That is rooted in the fact that angels are incarnation of all excellence, and therefore approach us once we resemble them and turn away from us when we resemble any Satanic characteristics. So there's a reason more than just public appeal in looking and smelling nice in mosques.

Comment: -1, The question has source-identification tag. It is asking if source exists. and not explanation of the hadith

Comment: @Sohaeb, [we decided](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16100623#16100623) that the question is not asking for source-identification because then it would count as a duplicate. Judging by the content and title it seems to be about hadith interpretation, and that makes my answer valid.

Comment: Uh-huh, @infatuated, yea. Actually Judging by the content and title it seems to be about hadith interpretation, and that makes you answer valid. Well done.